# Meaning of "en" in "mais le titre m’en paraissait si ridicule que"

Tags: pronoms, verbes

The question is on *en* as highlighted in this passage from La porte étroite by André Gide.

> Grande émotion, en passant rue de Paris avant-hier, de voir, à la devanture de M…, bien indiscrètement étalé, le livre d’Abel que tu m’avais annoncé, mais à la réalité duquel je ne parvenais pas à croire. Je n’ai pu y tenir ; je suis entrée ; mais le titre m’**en** paraissait si ridicule que j’hésitais à le dire au commis ; j’ai même vu l’instant où j’allais ressortir de la boutique avec n’importe quel autre ouvrage. Heureusement, une pente pile de Privautés attendait le client, près du comptoir – où j’ai jeté cent sous, après m’être emparée d’un exemplaire, et sans avoir eu besoin de parler.

**QUESTION**

1. Is *en* a pronoun referring to the book?
2. If yes, is it normal for *titre* and *en* to be separated like that (by *me*)?
3. Can we just drop *en* since there is only one thing *le titre* can be the title of?
4. Can we drop *en* but relplace *le titre* with *son titre*?
5. Alternatively, is *en paraître* a set phrase?
6. If yes to 5, how is *en paraître* different from *paraître*?
7. If no to 1 and no to 5, what is the contribution of *en* to the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*En* is indeed referring to the book. It is normal for the *me* to come before *en*. When there are multiple object pronouns *en* is closest to the verb<sup>1</sup>.

Another way of writing the sentence would be:

> Je n’ai pu y tenir ; je suis entrée ; mais le titre de ce livre me paraissait si ridicule que j’hésitais à le dire au commis.

or

> Je n’ai pu y tenir ; je suis entrée ; mais son titre me paraissait si ridicule que j’hésitais à le dire au commis.

*En* could also be omitted:

> mais le titre me paraissait si ridicule que j’hésitais à le dire au commis ;

without really impairing the comprehension of the sentence because the context is clear. But to my ears the sentence sounds better using *en*.

*En paraitre* is not a set phrase as far as I know, I haven't been able to think of a single instance where *en* would not be justified in the sentence, it always represents something that has been named before (or will be named soon).

<sup>1 **Usual order of  object pronouns:** 
direct object (1st or 2nd Person) and *se* , direct object (3rd Person), indirect object, *y*, *en*.  [Here's](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/315.html) a good recap.</sup>.